# Integrating Java compiler in my application

Tags: java

I want to integrate java compiler in my application but I don't have any idea how will I do that.
I want that user could compile and run code on my application.
If anyone can help me then please tell me from where I should start.

Comment: This perhaps: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html

Answer (score 7):

Starting Java 1.6, the standard JDK ships with an API to the compiler. Meaning, you can easily write a Java program that will compile other programs.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html

**EDIT** as per Aaron's comment: an application using the compiler API must be run using the full JDK. The JRE doesn't include the compiler API implementation.

Comment: Note that you need to run your application with the JDK for this to work. A JRE is no longer enough when use this API. Specifically, you need the `tools.jar`.

Answer (score 0):

A second alternative is to embed the Eclipse Java compiler into your code. The advantage of this is that your application doesn't need a SDK to run - just add this single JAR.

Details are documented here: http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftask-using_batch_compiler.htm

Note: Adding a compiler to an application creates an enormous security risk. It basically means anyone can start doing anything with your application. Things that spring to mind are:

- Attacking other computers, people and sites
- Looking at all the data on the computer on which the application is running
- Analyzing the network the computer is in and attacking any other computer in the same network
- Installing Trojans or viruses on the computer

Comment: Just asking for curiosity, how do the sites like hackerrank, topcoder prevent security risks? In order to compete, you have to submit some java or c++ code of desired algorithm and I am assuming they run those codes on the server side. Scanning through all file system and deleting files is possible with java or c. Would it make sense to keep some "blacklist" keywords in order to prevent that?(like if you see BufferedReader then don't run the code.)